# Apply condition class to v-col

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm trying to apply condition class to my v-col

```
<v-row v-for="(rule, index) in ruleDetails" :key="index">
<v-col
    :class="{
        'md-4': rule.width == 'large',
        'md-3': rule.width == 'medium'
    }"
>
    
</v-col>
</v-row
```

and `rule.width = 'medium'` right now.

It doesn't seem to take any effect.

Did I forget something ?

Answer (score 1):

You can make it an array.

```js
<v-row v-for="(rule, index) in ruleDetails" :key="index">
  <v-col :class="[rule.width == 'large' && 'md-4', rule.width == 'medium' && 'md-3']">
    
  </v-col>
</v-row
```

This resolves in `:class="[false, 'md-3']` which Vue parses to `<foo class="md-3" />`

```js
const rule = {
  width: 'medium'
}

console.log([rule.width == 'large' && 'md-4', rule.width == 'medium' && 'md-3'])
```

Comment: Is this the only way, the syntax is kind horrible;

Answer (score 0):

You can use `md` attribute directly in `<v-col>` instead of class. To achieve this, You can apply one more property as value along with width in each object.

Demo (Run this code snippet in full page) **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    ruleDetails: [{
      width: 'small',
      value: 2
    }, {
      width: 'medium',
      value: 3
    }, {
      width: 'large',
      value: 4
    }]
   }),
});
```

```css
#app { padding: 1% 5% }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-row v-for="(rule, index) in ruleDetails" :key="index">
    <v-col :md="rule.value" style="background-color: yellow">
      {{ rule.width }}
    </v-col>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</div>
```